# change background every <li> generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list that is generated by javascript every time someone adds an item:
the html looks like this:

```
<ul class="items-listed-rc">
    <li>1 generated by javascript</li>
    <li>2 generated by javascript</li>
    <li>3 generated by javascript</li>
    <li>4 generated by javascript</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

currently all are with the blue background, I would like the

2 and 4 have different background and so continued .. Blue, red, blue, red, blue, red ...

Comment: where are you running in to a problem i see no code  ?

Comment: add classes to the generated `<li>` item you want red or blue and in css match the class with the color you want. very simple fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector nth-child:

```
.items-listed-rc li:nth-child(even){
    background:red;
}​
```

**Edit**

As jay Harris mentioned, the CSS selector nth-child is not supported by IE8 and below.
You can use jQuery for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".items-listed-rc li:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
});
```

CSS:

```
.items-listed-rc li.even{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: you should note that this isn't available in IE 8 and earlier

Comment: [IE8 is still fairly popular](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201306-201307-bar) so it is worth considering alternatives such as the new edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this using javascript, you could do

```
$(".items-listed-rc li:odd").css("background-color", "red")
$(".items-listed-rc li:even").css("background-color", "blue")
```

Otherwise css options are better as don't require adding extra js code, just we aware of selectors compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you're adding the list items. Probably the best way, as others have mentioned, is to use the [`nth-child()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child), but iE8 and below doesn't support it.

If you're generating with JS, you could use a counter or the [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9f59bza0%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

```
var ul = document.getElementById("items");
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");

   // Set odd/even class name 
    li.className = (i%2 == 1 ? "odd" : "even" );

    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("#"+i+" Created with JavaScript"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/xBcFQ/